# how to catch 'next' button on soft keyboard of Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 6 Edittexts grouped in 6 differents layouts, all in the same view.
My problem is that my app is forced to landscape mode, and by pressing the 'next' button i want to automatically start to edit another editText rather than the one android set me by default. Example: i'm writing on EditText1, press next, and focus is taken by the EditText that is UNDER the 1st one. I want to edit the one that is RIGHT to it.

Sorry for my bad english :(
The device is a galaxy tab, with Google API8/Android 2.2
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but this should work

```
 some_edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                some_button.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This actually worked..i just put editText.requestfocus(true); in the if satement.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I don't think there is any implicit way of doing it. You would need to write your own `EditorAction`.

You need to monitor everything that the user enters and whenever he presses **'NEXT'**, you would have to manually shift the focus to the next EditText, using [EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT).

Comment: Not TextWatcher, but EditorAction I think, then EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT sounds good.